# Is it possible to use objects with different rows count in Keras LSTM?

Tags: python, keras

For example, I have data such as:

```
x1 = np.random.random((10,3))
x2 = np.random.random((5,3))
```

And so on. The point is: all x[i] have same y-size, different x-size and I need to use NumPy array (because Keras needs NumPy array, as far as I understand) with shape (trainSetSize, None, 3) to fit the model. For this, I'm trying to use such model structure:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(2, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(None, 3)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I concat arrays x1, x2, ..., xN this way:

```
arr = np.array([x1,x2],dtype=object)
```

And gettind arr.shape (2,) and getting the following error from Keras:

```
Error when checking input: expected lstm_2_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 1)
```

So, is there a way to fit Keras on 3d-array with different rows count by object?

Comment: can you try making each x1,x2,. . .  as a list like [x1], [x2],. . . Some thing like this to add new dimension arr = np.array([[x1], [x2]], dtype=object)

Comment: I even tried to use np.array of np.arrays. And concatting like np.concatenate((a,b[np.newaxis,:])) didn't do anything useful.
I think the point is Keras needs just one array which can contain multiple dimension. But in such array I can't use rows with different sizes.

Comment: Then i guess Padding to the longest sequence in the batch(if using batch processing) or longest sequence in the entire set is an option.